# How to find the surface area of rotary solid.

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

> What is the surface area of solid generated by rotating the parametric curve $x=\cos\left(\frac{\pi u}{2}\right)\ $ ($\forall \ \ 0\le u\le 1$) about x-axis through $360^\circ$ ?

My try:

I treated $u$ as an independent variable $x$ & variable $x$ as dependent variable $y$ then the equation can be re-written as

$y=\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)$

$y'=-\frac\pi2 \sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)$

The surface area of rotary solid

$=\int_0^1 2\pi y\sqrt{1+(y')^2}\ dx$

$=\int_0^1 2\pi \cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\sqrt{1+\left(-\frac\pi2 \sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\right)^2}\ dx$

$=\frac8\pi\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac\pi2 \sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\right)^2}\ d\left(\frac\pi2\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\right)$

$=\frac12\left(\sqrt2+\ln(1+\sqrt2)\right)$

But my teacher says that the correct answer is $2\pi$ sq.unit, I don't where I am wrong. Please tell me where I am wrong & help me solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Since the curve is given as a parametric curve we should specify non only x=x(u) but also y=y(u). What is y in your case?

Comment: @gimusi: yes, you are right. There should be another variable $y$ in terms of $u$. Probably It should be $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi u}{2}\right)$. Am I right?

Comment: Let check that point!

Answer (score 1):

The data you have given seems not complete.

Assuming as parametric curve

- $x=\cos\left(\frac{\pi u}{2}\right)$
- $y=u$

we have

$$x=\cos\left(\frac{\pi y}{2}\right)\implies y=\frac 2 \pi\arccos x \implies y'=-\frac 2 \pi\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

and therefore we obtain (see numerical evaluation [**here**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%204*arccos%20x*(1%2B(4%2Fpi%5E2)*1%2F(1-x%5E2))%5E.5%20dx%20x%3D0..1))

$$S=\int_0^1 2\pi  \cdot \frac 2 \pi\arccos x\sqrt{1+\frac4{\pi^2}\frac1{1-x^2}}\,dx\approx 5.14$$

Assuming, according to your comment, as parametric curve

- $x=\cos\left(\frac{\pi u}{2}\right)$
- $y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi u}{2}\right)$

we have that the cordinates describe a quarter of a circle and in that case we obtain

$$V=\frac12 \cdot 4\pi=2\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

first plot **x vs u** graph by **varying u from 0 to 1** (you will get a quardant with radius 1 )

then, rotate your curve about x axis . you'll get hemisphere of radius $1$ giving surface area =$2\pi $ sq. units

Answer (score 0):

This is not a parametric curve.  When you change your variables from $u$ to $x$ and $x$ to $y$, then you also have to change them in the phrase "about the $x$-axis" to 
"about the $y$-axis.  So your integral should be

$$\int_0^1 2\pi x \sqrt{1+(y')^2} \; dx.$$

And that has a numerical value of about $5.1$, so there's 
no way the right answer is $2\pi.$